# Smooth algebraic varieties with smooth Kahler quotients.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $V$ be a smooth algebraic variety defined over complex numbers. Suppose that $G$ admits a free discrete  action on $V$ so that $V/G$ is compact and Kahler (or algebraic). Is it ture that $G$ is virtually abelian (i.e., contains an abelian subgroup of finite index)?

If we don't ask $V/G$ to be algebraic (Kahler) there are lots of counterexamples, we can take 
a complex Lie group and quotient it by a co-compact lattice. But if $V/G$ is algebraic
the only example that I can imagine is when $V\cong M\times \mathbb C^n$, where M is compact and $G$ preserves the product. Are there other examples?  This question is related to 
[Is the complex moduli of Quintic Calabi-Yau toric?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36388/is-the-complex-moduli-of-quintic-calabi-yau-toric)

ADDED. Note that a compact complex nilmanifold, i.e. a complex manifold with a homogenious action of a nilpotent group is Kahler iff it is a trous, http://www.jstor.org/pss/2047375 . So a quotient of a complex nilpotent group by a co-compact subgroup never provides a counter-example.

Comment: I am not sure that this is correct, but have you tried upper triangular matrices over the complex numbers, divided out by the action of the upper triangular matrices with entries in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Comment: Damiano: Your construction (for matrices of size at least $3\times 3$) gives a non-Kähler variety (it has non-closed 1-forms).

Comment: @Torsten: thanks for the answer! I was indeed stuck on proving that the quotient was Kaehler. I still think that "nilpotent" might be a better fit than "virtually abelian"...

Comment:  My earlier comment was wrong so I deleted it.There are examples of
compact kahler manifolds with nilpotent fundamental groups due to
Campana and Carlson-Toledo.Their universal cover maybe an algebraic 
variety.

Comment: How your question is related to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36388/is-the-complex-moduli-of-quintic-calabi-yau-toric?

Comment: Well, in this question I make the guess -- that for a "generic" variety with infinite fundamental group its universal cover is not algebraic. Namely that if the fundamental group of the vairety is not virtually abelian, then the universal cover is not algebraic. For plenty of moduli spaces their fundamental group is not virtually ableian (in particular for the moduli spaces of quintics). If what I ask were correct, this would say that Teichmuller space is not algebraic (and hence surely can not be toric). This is the realtion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following article http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2762 of BENOÎT CLAUDON, ANDREAS HÖRING, AND JÁNOS KOLLÁR answers positively the question, provided $V/G$ is projective, $V$ is quasiprojective and $\pi_1(V)=0$.  Moreover, assuming abundance conjecture, they prove under the above conditions that $V$ is biholomophric to the product of $\mathbb C^n$ with a simply-connected variety.

**Added.** Interestingly, if we ask that $V/G$ is merely Kahler, the question seems to be open even for $V=\mathbb C^n$ for $n\ge 4$. It is related to (and follows immediately from) "Iitaka's conjecture" predicting that any such compact Kahler quotient  $\mathbb C^n/G$ has a finite cover bi-holomorphic to a torus. Iitaka conjecture is discussed in the article  "UNIFORMISATION IN DIMENSION FOUR:
TOWARDS A CONJECTURE OF IITAKA" of Horing, Peternell, and Radloff :  http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.5392